# Google Drive or Google Cloud Storage

Tags: backup, google-drive, google-cloud-storage

I intend to implement a storage solution to backup

- a couple of Linux platforms (via [rclone](http://rclone.org/))
- a couple of Macs
- a couple of iPhones

having in mind

- recovering data would be just in case of a computer failure (i.e. usually no need to read data from the storage)
- using an existing iPhone App to automatically backup (mainly pictures)
- no need of extensive data space (1 TB max)

There are good reviews about Google services, but between Drive and Cloud Storage, which one would best fit my requirements above?

Comment: You should pick the one that best suites your needs.

Comment: Actually have no experience with either service, and tries to get an answer from knowledgeable people here.

Comment: Your question is seeking our opinion.  Please read the help center to better understand what type of questions are on topic here at Superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive is generally aimed at actual humans that want to back up and share personal files. Google Cloud Storage is designed to be used by programs to store and retrieve objects. If your goal involves writing a program to store and retrieve data, Google Cloud Storage may be right for you. If you just want a place that you can put your files, that's Google Drive.